# Suspended mass in motion free-body diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

> A 20kg mass is held by two ropes which span 90 from each other. The mass is being accelerated at 1m/s^2 to the right. Draw a free body diagram for the mass and find the numerical values for each force acting on the mass.

Solved

[image: Here]

Comment: Use Newton's Second Law